# Creating a mobile site by adding a new class to the body tag from functions.php

Tags: php, functions, css, mobile

Essentially is there a way to use a function in functions.php to turn the `<body>` tag into `<body class="mobile">`? I have code that recognizes mobile devices but right now it's set up to load a mobile.php page `include(STYLESHEETPATH."/mobile.php");`, which isn't quite what I want.

I've tried all sorts of mobile site plugins like WP mobile, mobify, etc. None of them work the way I want and I'd rather not mess with that anymore. Please don't suggest that.

I know this is kind of a newbie question but I can't find any info on it anywhere.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

The code below works, basically it adds your class to the wordpress body_class() array..

```
add_filter('body_class','my_class_names');
function my_class_names($classes) {
    // add 'class-name' to the $classes array
    $classes[] = 'mobile';
    // return the $classes array
    return $classes;
}
```

You can read more on this on the WP codex [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class#Adding_More_Classes)